# Difference in Logical Statement between [,] and $

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, logic

I am working on a data frame ('df_temp') with two columns customer id ('Custid') and income ('Income'):

```
  Custid    Income
  <fctr>     <dbl>
1   1003  29761.20
2   1004  98249.55
3   1006  23505.30
4   1007  72959.25
5   1009 114973.95
6   1010  25038.30
```

While checking if Income is numeric, I am facing the following problem:

Using $ to refer to Income, returns TRUE:

```
> is.numeric(df_temp$Income)
[1] TRUE
```

Using [,2] or [,which(...)] to refer to Income, returns FALSE:

```
> i <- which(names(df_temp)=='Income')
> is.numeric(df_temp[,i])
[1] FALSE
> is.numeric(df_temp[,2])
[1] FALSE
```

When trying to set this vector to numerical using [,], I run into another issue:

```
> df_temp[,2] <- as.numeric(df_temp[,2])
```

> ```
> Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
> ```

I always thought that $ and [] serve the same purpose when referring to a vector in a data frame.

Could somebody please help me understanding the problem and converting this vector into numerical, using the [,] expression?

Comment: You have a `tb_df` object

Comment: What is the result of `str(df_temp[,2])`?

Comment: @jogo, it is:

Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 2431 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Income: num  29761 98250 23505 72959 114974 ...

Comment: From your output, you are not working with a data.frame object. Most likely, hadley made some change as to how to reference this type of object. You should list the names of all relevant packages that your are using in your question.

Comment: @JanBenedikt So you see: it is not a numeric vector. `df_temp` is not a *dataframe object*! `[` on your object operates not the same way as for dataframes. See the answer of akrun or Joshua!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not working with a data.frame. You're working with a "tbl_df". Subsetting a tbl_df using `$` returns a vector. Subsetting a tbl_df using `[` returns a tbl_df, and a tbl_df is not a numeric vector, so `is.numeric` returns `FALSE`.

One thing tbl_df does is uses `drop = FALSE` when calling `[`. But it goes even further by actively preventing you from setting `drop = TRUE`:

```
x <- tbl_df(mtcars)
is.numeric(x[,"cyl",drop=TRUE])
# [1] FALSE
Warning messages:
1: drop ignored
```

So, you cannot use `[` with a tbl_df in the way you want. You have to use `$` or `[[` to extract the vector.

```
is.numeric(x$cyl)
# [1] TRUE
is.numeric(x[["cyl"]])
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: @RichScriven: that assumes I looked at other answers while writing mine. When I started, there were no answers.  I also don't use the "strategy" of submitting a short, incomplete answer in order to be "first", and then edit it to completeness before the 5-minute initial edit window runs out.

Answer (score 3):

To fully answer the question, $ and [ do serve the same purpose on a standard data.frame object:

```
Custid <- c(1003, 1004, 1006, 1007, 1009, 1010)
Income <- c(29761.20, 98249.55, 23505.30, 72959.25, 114973.95, 25038.30)
mydf <- data.frame(Custid, Income)
class(mydf$Income); class(mydf[ , 2])
```

You're dealing with a `tbl_df` object:

```
library(dplyr)
mytbl_df <- tbl_df(mydf)
print(mytbl_df)
## A tibble: 6 × 2
#  Custid    Income
#   <dbl>     <dbl>
#1   1003  29761.20
#2   1004  98249.55
#3   1006  23505.30
#4   1007  72959.25
#5   1009 114973.95
#6   1010  25038.30
```

To get [ to work as usual on mytbl_df, just convert it back into a data.frame: `newdf <- as.data.frame(mytbl_df)`.

Answer (score 1):

We have a `tbl_df` object, so extracting using `[` still is a `tbl_df` i.e.

```
df_temp[,i]
# A tibble: 6 × 1
#     Income
#      <dbl>
#1  29761.20
#2  98249.55
#3  23505.30
#4  72959.25
#5 114973.95
#6  25038.30
```

We can do the `[[` extraction

```
df_temp[[i]]
#[1]  29761.20  98249.55  23505.30  72959.25 114973.95  25038.30


is.numeric(df_temp[[i]])
#[1] TRUE
```

#### data

```
df_temp <- structure(list(Custid = c(1003L, 1004L, 1006L, 1007L, 1009L, 
1010L), Income = c(29761.2, 98249.55, 23505.3, 72959.25, 114973.95, 
25038.3)), .Names = c("Custid", "Income"), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```